# How to install Ubuntu from USB and not delete Windows XP

Tags: windows, usb-drive, windows-xp

My computer currently runs on Win XP, and I would like to install Ubuntu 12.04.
I downloaded the ISO file, booted a USB, and restarted my netbook.
I selected the option to install Ubuntu along Windows XP, but it shows up a window that requires the partition division.

What must I do to run Ubuntu along Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

Manually changing the partitions as part of the installation process is relatively straightforward.  See [Manual partitioning](http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/manual-partitioning/)  for an example and a number of helpful links including some to video tutorials.

Comment: Anyway, it says "No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu"...what should I do?!